Handling exceptions when calling stored procedures in hibernate
I'm currently using hibernate and I have this piece of code in java:
 ProcedureCall pc = session.createStoredProcedureCall("sp_test");
 pc.getOutputs()

Stored procedure in SQL Server:
create procedure sp_test
as
     raiserror('error', 16, 1)

I'm trying to catch error throwing from SQL Server by wrapping up in try block but didn't seem to catch anything
How can I resolve this? Thanks for reading my problem

Side note: you should not use the sp_ prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use (see Naming Stored Procedures), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's also bad for your stored procedure performance. It's best to just simply avoid sp_ and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!
